# OneNote COM Addin only loads manually

Tags: com, ms-office, office-addins, onenote

I have been working on a COM add-in for OneNote based on the tutorial at http://www.malteahrens.com/#/blog/howto-onenote-dev/ and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2555352.  It builds fine, however, when I load OneNote, I have to manually go through to options to start the add in.  It tells me a "runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM add-in."  Once the add-in is loaded manually it works as it should.  I've been searching around on the internet for a while without much luck.

I have tried looking at Fusion logs, but can't make any sense of the errors:

`LOG: Download of application configuration file was attempted from file:///C:/Windows/SysWOW64/DllHost.exe.config.
    LOG: Configuration file C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DllHost.exe.config does not exist.
    LOG: No application configuration file found.
    LOG: Using host configuration file: 
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/SysWOW64/CSOneNoteRibbonAddIn.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/SysWOW64/CSOneNoteRibbonAddIn/CSOneNoteRibbonAddIn.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/SysWOW64/CSOneNoteRibbonAddIn.EXE.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/SysWOW64/CSOneNoteRibbonAddIn/CSOneNoteRibbonAddIn.EXE.`

I have also tried try catch blocks with logging with no luck.  I am using VS 2010 Pro. Thanks.